# iOS - Do I need to re-submit in-app purchases after rejecting binary

Tags: ios, binary, in-app-purchase

Yesterday I set up 2 in-app purchases then uploaded the binary to go with them. Today I rejected the binary and immediately submitted another. Yesterday's in-app purchases are still showing as waiting for review. 
I guess this means I don't need to redo and re-submit them as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll only need to resubmit in-app-purchases if they are moved to the "Developer Action Required" state. So as it stands right now, you should be fine.

Apple Support would be able to provide a much better answer though (anyone here would only be able to give you responses based on research and past experiences, which often are different from the present); you may want to shoot them an email.

Answer (score 0):

"waiting for review" means they haven't even touched your binary yet. You're good.